# How do you use sphinx to search for urls

Tags: sphinx

I have millions of URLs in a mysql database. I'm using sphinx to index them, but sphinx is having trouble with the periods in the urls. How do you go about indexing urls in sphinx so that it handles the periods when I search?

I guess I just want it to ignore the periods?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the periods to the

> charset_table

Hopes this help.

Comment: I've been doing this

 charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, ., U+A8->U+B8, U+B8, U+C0..U+DF->U+E0..U+FF, U+E0..U+FF, U+2E, U+2D, U+40, U+3D, U+002F, U+0028, U+0029